# How can we add a comma in publisher name in appxmanifest while using desktop app converter to convert my win32 app into UWP app

Tags: powershell, windows, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

```
.\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -ExpandedBaseImage C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14316

–Installer C:\Users\chris\Downloads\x\x.exe -InstallerArguments "/S" -Destination C:\Output\x

-PackageName "VLC" -Publisher "CN=Company,name" -Version 0.2.2.2 -MakeAppx -Verbose
```

So the comodo certificate i am having for my app has a comma in the CN , i.e. ,something like `CN="Comapany, NAme"`

How can i pass this in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation about appxmanifest you can include comma in publisher name without a problem as long as the publisher name is surrounded by quotes ("):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211441.aspx

So the real question is how to pass publisher name with quotes to AppConverter.

The solution seem to be to represent " with \"\" when passing publisher like this:

```
-Publisher 'CN=\"\"Company, Name\"\"'
```

The full command here:

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer myInstaller.exe -InstallerArguments "/S" -Destination . -PackageName "MyApp" -Publisher 'CN=\"\"Company, Name\"\"' -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx
```

However there seems to be a bug in DesktopAppConverter. The result I get is this:

CN="Company, Name

The 2nd " is missing from the result. I'm not sure why DesktopAppConverter is unable to recognize the 2nd \"\" special character, but that's the case and so we're unfortunately stuck here.

**Update:** Found the solution. With trial and error I found out that adding double quote "" helps in recognizing the 2nd quote. So the following works:

```
-Publisher 'CN=\"\"Company, Name""\"\"'
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution and it still does not work for me. I've tried both

'CN=\"\"Company, LLC\"\"'

and

'CN=\"\"Company, LLC""\"\"'

in both cases I get errors from MakeAppX saying that the publisher name is invalid. In one cases, the error shows the name as:

"Company, LLC"""

and in the second case as:

"Company, LLC""""

Has anyone been able to make this actually work?

Comment: My solution above worked for me but it turned out you don't need it anyways because you shouldn't put your company name as "Publisher" anyways. After I contacted Microsoft I realized that the "Publisher" should be the Publisher ID that they generate for you when you sign up for Microsoft App Developer account. Do you have an account?

Comment: I keep trying and it still does not work.  

When the appx package is signed, the Publisher entry has to match the digital id used in signing, so if the certificate has a comma in it, you have to use this in the Publisher field, so it is needed.

Is there anything I'm missing that it does not work for me?  I'm running the command using Powershell.

Comment: Before I help you include comma, let me save you time by letting you know that you don't even need a certificate. Are you planning to submit your app to Windows Appstore? If so then you shouldn't sign it with your own certificate because Microsoft only accept "unsigned" apps. After your app is approved Microsoft will sign it with their own certificate.

Comment: I'll try this, but it is still disturbing that we cannot sign the appx package just because there is a comma in the publisher's name.

Answer (score 1):

In AppXManifest.xml, the comma can embed in a `&quot;` string:

```
<Identity Name="VLC" Publisher="CN=&quot;Comapany, NAme&quot;" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me the fix was two-folded as I described on my [blog](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2018/01/16/use-comma-publisher-field-using-desktop-app-converter/):

1. Use a space after the command in the Publisher field: e.g. `CN=Company, Name=Foo`
2. Launch the Desktop App Converter from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the comma, that is use `-Publisher "CN=Company&comma;name"`.